# Column above another in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm looking for a way to put a bootstrap column above another. I have an image on the left, a text which is partially coming above it, and on my text column, the title is aligned just after the image (so not above it).

Here is what I want to do : [image]

First, I was trying to make to rows and use negative margins but it doesn't fit correctly. I thought something with ::before can help but I don't really now how to solve this right.

Thanks in advance for your precious help !

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will seek around the `z-index` property for my text (in example: 101) and a lower one (in example: 100) (or default one) for my image which I need to display below it.

1 bootstrap 5 colum with the css class `col-12` and the image and the text inside it with the following stuff :

- `w-50` on the image
- `w-75 bg-transparent` on the text or apply the same background to that div container for your text.
- your background css classes for the stylized row containing them all.

You can use [ratios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/) and [positions](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/) for your text.
At least I will try it first, after adopting any other strategy.

Comment: I tried what you say but I don't understand exactly how it solves the problem.

I now have a col-sm-12, with an img with the w-50 class, and a div for my text+title with w-75 and bg-transparent but there is no way to go above the image with this?

Comment: Create css classes with z-index property set as given and play/apply to your div elts contained inside your col-sm-12, and d-inline could help, maybe.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, nothing happen. I can't show you here in comment so I don't know how but maybe we can speak in DM or anything else ? (by the way I just seen you are french, I'm also ;) )

Comment: Up please, didn’t succeed